# How to check and request if a seclet form open the next page

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I want to make the a href tag to open the next page only if the user select the form from the cart inventory so If the user doesn t select the color and the size he cant open the next page(confimation page the order)

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post"><td data-th="Dimensiuni" ><select name="size" id="sizeValue" style="width:8em" required>';
        <option class="form-control text-center"  value="" >Alege...</option>';
        <option class="form-control text-center"   value="'.$size.'">'.$size.'(avaible: '.$cantitateLibera.')</option>';

        </select>';

    //to open the confirmation page<a href="test.php" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> Pasul următor <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

Update: suppose i have the follow array mulltidimensional ... like `Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 2 [pretProdus] => 750 [sizeChange] => R2 [culoare] => Mov ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 11  [sizeChange] => N/a [pretProdus] => 151 ) )` how i can take the loop in java, sorry but I m new at javascript

Comment: I don't understand what the array has to do with this question. That's a PHP array, nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: Why are you using an `<a>` tag instead of a submit button for the form? If you use a normal submission, the `required` attributes will prevent it from submitting if the user hasn't selected something.

Comment: because i use two form select and also a loop.. i didnot putted here to not complicate the question

Comment: If you don't post it here, we can't understand what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `onclick` check in the anchor tag:

```
<a href="test.php" onclick="return check_select('size')" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> Pasul următor <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

The function can be like:

```
function check_select(id) {
    return !!document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

If `check_select()` returns `false`, the default action of clicking on the link is disabled.

Comment: ok suppose if I have 2 select `size` and `color` how to write that?`<a href="test.php" onclick="return check_select('size''color')" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> Pasul următor <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
`

Comment: `return check_select('size') && check_select('color')`

Comment: Or you could change the function to take an array of IDs, and loop through them.

Comment: suppose i have the follow array mulltidimensional ... like `Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 2 [pretProdus] => 750 [sizeChange] => R2 [culoare] => Mov ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 11  [sizeChange] => N/a [pretProdus] => 151 ) ) ` how i can take the loop in java, sorry but I m new at javascript

Comment: Add it to the question, don't try to put complicated questions in comments.